# Why do some parties but not others have logos in the new Dutch ballot paper (stembiljet)?

Tags: election, netherlands

In the new ballot paper (stembiljet) for the Dutch general election, 2017, some parties have logos whereas others do not, as shown below.  Why?

[image: Dutch ballot for voters abroad]
*Source: http://www.stemmenvanuithetbuitenland.nl*

---

Translation of the ballot paper (*Stembiljet*):

> Ballot paper for the election of members of the Second Chamber of the States-General on Wednesday 15 March 2017.
>
> Step 1: in step one, colour the white circle for the list of your choice red, black, blue, or green.
>
> Step 2:  Colour at step two the white dot at the number of the candidate of your choice red, black, blue, or green.
>
> Names of candidates are listed in the candidate overview.
> Be careful: first choose a list in step 1 or your vote will be invalid.

The actual ballot (stembiljet) I received in the mail looks identical.
*NB: I am voting from abroad and this is a new layout for the ballot paper (stembiljet).  I believe voters in The Netherlands receive the old version, which does not include logos for any party.*

I *suspect* it is because those parties [did not register their logos](https://www.kiesraad.nl/verkiezingen/inhoud/tweede-kamer/partijnamen-en-logos/registreren-logo-partij) but that is just speculation.

Comment: I'm tempted to point out logos on StackOverflow policy (those who pay get to have a logo on a tag :)

Comment: Is stembiljet the dutch word for ballot?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Yes

Comment: I deleted some comments which were asking about other aspects of the Dutch election system which were not relevant to this question. But some of these were interesting and should be asked as new questions.

Comment: Aren't those just the ballots used for voting abroad? Here they [looked like this (for TK2017)](http://www.politiekdelft.nl/stembiljet-tk2017-hfvh-20170315175448.jpg).

Comment: @JJJ Kiesraad plans to change the Stembiljet for elections to the linked design, and at the last elections, voters abroad were trialing the new design.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've already answered your own question: parties didn't register their logo, or didn't do it on time. This is really the only possible answer, since the only *other* possible answer would be that the government chose to give some parties a preferential position on the ballot.

This is [confirmed by D66 MP Eelco Keij](https://eelcokeij.com/2017/02/17/uw-stembiljet-al-binnen-faq-artikel-trouw-stemproces-aankomende-presentaties/), who got the following reply  from election office in The Hague (which is responsible for elections from abroad) when he asked this question:

> **Why are the logos of some parties missing on the voting ballot?**
>   The parties should have registered their logo. Some parties have not done this, or did not do this on time.

Why didn't some parties do this? Probably for the same reason that many a  company has found their website to have gone dark after they forgot to extend the registration period of their domain names: unclear responsibilities, someone forgetting to do it, or "lost" in the bureaucracy.
Furthermore, registering logos is new, and in 2017 this ballot was only used for voters from abroad as an experiment (a regular Dutch ballot [looks like this](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/C568sxYWAAAD_5S.jpg); no logos), so many parties probably don't have standard procedure for it yet, and given that it applies to a small percentage of all ballots it may not have been a huge priority either.